# Unable to transition the SkyBox in Unity5 slowly

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is my very first time on creating a unity game and I'm stuck with the 
skybox transition. I was able to transition the skybox by the following code, however , what I want to do is to transition into another skybox slowly, not instantly.

I simply want to transition the current skybox to the matbox that has been passed slowly when the player has 1 or less life left. But I have no clue how to add a logic to add a slow transition. I would love to hear from you !

```
void Update () {

        if (life <= 1 ) {

            RenderSettings.skybox = matbox;
        }
```

Comment: You'd probably have to write your own skybox shader that has this feature

Comment: Do you know any helpful site or link that helps total beginners with creating custom skybox shaders ?

Comment: Learn how to make basic shaders first and take a look at this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Unity/Skyboxes